# Why getting error The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate, private-key

I've developed a windows service application in C#.NET and now trying to call a web service from this windows service which is developed in Java. My client provided me with the certificate with .cert type and private key in .pkcs8 type. When I try to call the web service then I get the following error:

> The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate.

Here is my code to connect with wsdl:

```
<clientCredentials>
 <serviceCertificate>
  <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="CurrentUser" />
 </serviceCertificate>
 <clientCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="Root" findValue="176455DB76886FF2BA3C122F8B36322F647CB2FD" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>                     
</clientCredentials>
```

I would appreciate most if you could suggest me on the above to know how to include the private key with this certificate to call the web service from my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us a calling part?

Comment: Use OpenSSL to merge the certificate and its private key to a PFX file. Then import that to your certificate store. Currently you have imported only the certificate which triggered the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you imported your certificate to Windows Certificate store, but haven't associated with a private key. You have to merge `.cer` and `.pkcs8` files into PFX container. You can use `certutil.exe` too for that:

```
certutil -mergepfx path\mycert.cer path\mycert.pfx
```

**Note:** rename your key file to have matching to certificate file name and change extension to `.key`. That is, both files must be in the same folder and have names, like this: `mycert.cer`, `mycert.key`.